# Looping using two variables at a time in all possible combinations - UNIX

Tags: loops, unix, for-loop, while-loop

I need a command that uses all variables, two at a time in all possible combinations

Following this logic: (this command does not work, it's only an example):

```
for t1&t2 in 62 63 64 65; do 

echo "Horse $t1 and $t2" >> File.out 

done
```

and the final result would be

File.out

```
Horse 62 and 63  
Horse 62 and 64  
Horse 62 and 65
Horse 63 and 64
Horse 63 and 65
Horse 64 and 65
```

I want to use it, more specifically, with the R program like this way:

```
for t1&t2 in 62 63 64 65; do

 R -q -e "library(pastecs);d <- read.table('ageecent.txt', header = F,sep=' ');
vart1 =var(d[,$t1]); vres_t1=vart1*0.75; 
va_t1=(vart1*0.25);vart2=var(d[,$t2]); vres_t2=vart2*0.75; 
va_t2=(vart2*0.25); cor=cor(d[,$t1],d[,$t2]); 
write.table(va_t1,'va_t1', row.names=F, col.names=F);
write.table(vres_t1,'vres_t1',row.names=F,col.names=F);
write.table(va_t2,'va_t2',row.names=F,col.names=F);
write.table(vres_t2,'vres_t2',row.names=F,col.names=F);
write.table(cor,'cor',row.names=F,col.names=F)"

done
```

Where will I need to use two different variables at a time in all possible combinations, t1 and t2, that define the columns of my main file "ageecent.txt", that must be analyzed. Thank you for your attention and support.

Comment: You want to nest two loops, one inside the other. As easy as that.

Comment: Like this:

´For t1 in 62 64; do
For t2 in 63 64; do

echo "Horse $t1 and $t2" >> File.out

done
done´

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like what arkascha wrote. You only need to nest the for loop and add an if to check that both numbers are different. A bash example would look like:

```
#/bin/bash
NUMBERS="62 63 64 65"
for i in $NUMBERS; do
  for j in $NUMBERS; do
    if [ "$i" -ne "$j" ]; then
      echo "Horse $i and $j"
    fi
  done
done
```

which produces

```
Horse 62 and 63
Horse 62 and 64
Horse 62 and 65
Horse 63 and 62
Horse 63 and 64
Horse 63 and 65
Horse 64 and 62
Horse 64 and 63
Horse 64 and 65
Horse 65 and 62
Horse 65 and 63
Horse 65 and 64
```

*-- EDIT*

Without repetition of combinations of Numbers is possible too. You could use the array features of bash and basically program it or use the argument processing like the following (there are probably better looking ways, but it works):

```
#/bin/bash

NUMBERS="62 63 64 65"
LIST=$NUMBERS

dequeue_from_list() {
  shift;
  LIST=$@
}

for i in $NUMBERS; do
  dequeue_from_list $LIST
  for j in $LIST; do
    echo "Horse $i and $j"
  done
done
```

which produces

```
Horse 62 and 63
Horse 62 and 64
Horse 62 and 65
Horse 63 and 64
Horse 63 and 65
Horse 64 and 65
```

Comment: Well, I think I expressed myself wrong. Combinations as:
"Horse 63 and 64" and "Horse 64 and 63" are repeated, and I need one of these only. How can I do this?

Comment: Ok, so every combination only once and no combination of same numbers. Added some code for this.